# How to overlay total density and group density using ggdensity

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I want to generate a single density plot diagram that shows both the total density and group density plots.  For example, using the built in iris data set:

```
ggdensity(iris, x = "Sepal.Length",add = "mean")+
ggdensity(iris, x = "Sepal.Length", add = "mean", rug = TRUE,
          color = "Species", fill = "Species")
```

[image: Image produced by two ggdensity calls]

How do I get these to overlay into a single graph?

Comment: my attempt to inclue a copy of the output images from the above code failed!  In any event, it shows two graphs side by side.  I want to find a way to combine them into a single plot.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `geom_density` layer for the "grand total" density:

```r
ggdensity(iris, x = "Sepal.Length", add = "mean", rug = TRUE,
          color = "Species", fill = "Species") +
  geom_density()
```

[image]

Note though that the difference in the y axis scale is more apparent. If you want to fix this, you can multiply the grand total density by three and add a second axis:

```r
ggdensity(iris, x = "Sepal.Length", add = "mean", rug = TRUE,
          color = "Species", fill = "Species") +
  geom_density(aes(y = after_stat(density * 3))) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.x/3, name = 'Total density'))
```

[image]